# python remove elements from list based on other list

Tags: python, list

I'm stuck with a part in one of my codes where I have to delete all the occurances present in listA that are identical in listB.

Example:

```
A=[1,4,4,4,3,3,2,1,5,5]
B=[4,3]
```

Result should be `A=[1,2,1,5,5]`. Ideally I would want to do it in linear time.

Comment: sorry, theres a minor change in my question now. i would want my list A to have repeated values too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `list comprehension`,

```
In [11]: [i for i in A if i not in B]
Out[11]: [1, 2, 1, 5, 5]
```

Comment: sorry, theres a minor change in my question now. i would want my list A to have repeated values to

Comment: @SaiPardhu Changed accordingly

Comment: awesome, got it thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

using `Set Operations`:

```
list(set(A) - set(B))
```

Using `List Comprehension`

```
list(set([i for i in A if i not in B]))
```

Comment: Still there is a chance for duplicate elements,

Comment: sorry, theres a minor change in my question now. i would want my list A to have repeated values too